# VIsual Studio 2010 ultimate crashes when I make a SQL Server 2005 project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Every time I try to create a new SQL Server 2005 server project I get this error. Then after I hit ok Visual Studio 2010 crashes.

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version
>   3.5.1.0, Culture=neutrail, PublicKeyToke=89845dcd908080cc91' or
>   one of it dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified

Why can't it load this file?

Comment: I have no trouble at all to create a SQL Server project in my Visual Studio 2010 Professional. Hard to say - sounds like a problem local to your machine, I'd say. Can you try it on another machine, maybe?

Comment: I think it is a problem on my local machine not sure where though. I tried a repair on Vs2010 same problem.

Comment: Ok a restore through a backup image and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a repair install of VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had to do a restore to solve this problem. Not sure what happened but a restore fixed it.